# Strange things appear on running the program

Tags: c, list, sorting, malloc

I'm fixing a program but I'm facing a problem and I cant really realize what's the wrong on the code. I would appreciate any help.
I didn't post all the code, but I think with this part you can get an idea of it.
With the following function enter() I want to add user commands' data to a list.
   eg. user give the command: "en james bond 007 gun"   ["en" means "enter" on command prompt]

'james' is supposed to be the name, 'bond' the surname, 007 the amount and the rest is the description. I use strtok in order to 'cut' the command, then I put each name on a temp array. Then I call InsertSort in order to put the data on a linked list but in alphabetical order depending on the surname that users give. I want to keep the list on order and put each time the elements on the right position.

Also, maybe there is a fault on InsertSort() and SortedInsert()... as data aren't written on the list as they ought to.

```
/* struct for all the data that user enters on file */
typedef struct catalog    
{
       char short_name[50];                    
       char surname[50];                       
       signed int amount;                      
       char description[1000];              

       struct catalog *next;

}catalog,*catalogPointer;   

catalogPointer current;
catalogPointer head = NULL; 

void enter(void)//user command: en <name> <surname> <amount> <description>
{ int n,j=2,k=0;
 char temp[1500];
    char command[1500];

 while (command[j]!=' ' && command[j]!='\0') 
 { temp[k]=command[j];    
  j++;      
  k++;      
 }
 temp[k]='\0';      

 char *curToken = strtok(temp," ");   
 printf("temp is:%s \n",temp);

 char short_name[50],surname[50],description[1000];
 signed int amount;
 //short_name=(char *)malloc(sizeof (char *));
 //surname=(char *)malloc(sizeof (char *));
 //description=(char *)malloc(sizeof (char *));
 //amount=(int *)malloc(sizeof (int *));
 printf("\nWhat you entered for saving:\n");
 for (n = 0; curToken !='\0'; ++n)   
 { 
  if (curToken)
  { 
    strncpy(short_name, curToken, sizeof (char *)); /
  } 
  printf("Short Name: %s \n",short_name);    

  curToken = strtok(NULL," ");      
  if (curToken)
     strncpy(surname, curToken, sizeof (char *)); /
  printf("SurName: %s \n",surname);

  curToken = strtok(NULL," ");      
  if (curToken)
  {
     char *chk;     
     amount = (int) strtol(curToken, &chk, 10); 
    if (!isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0)
                    fprintf(stderr,"Warning: expected integer value for amount, received %s instead\n",curToken);
  }
  printf("Amount: %d \n",amount);
  curToken = strtok(NULL,"\0");     
  if (curToken)
    { strncpy(description, curToken, sizeof (char *));   
  }
  printf("Description: %s \n",description);
  break;
 }

 if (findEntryExists(head, surname) != NULL)
  printf("\nAn entry for <%s %s> is already in the catalog!\nNew entry not entered.\n",short_name,surname);
 else
 {
  printf("\nTry to entry <%s %s %d %s> in the catalog list!\n",short_name,surname,amount,description);
  InsertSort(&head,short_name, surname, amount, description);
  printf("\n**Entry done!**\n");
 }
 // Maintain the list in alphabetical order by surname.


}


/********Uses special case code for the head end********/
void SortedInsert(catalog** headRef, catalogPointer newNode,char short_name[],char surname[],signed int amount,char description[])
{
 strcpy(newNode->short_name, short_name);   
 strcpy(newNode->surname, surname);
 newNode->amount=amount;
 strcpy(newNode->description, description);

 // Special case for the head end
 if (*headRef == NULL||(*headRef)->surname >= newNode->surname)  
 {  newNode->next = *headRef;    
        *headRef = newNode;     
    }
    else 
 {       // Locate the node before the point of insertion
       catalogPointer current = *headRef;   
  catalogPointer temp=current->next;  
       while ( temp!=NULL )  
  {  
       if(strcmp(temp->surname,newNode->surname)<0 ) 
               current = temp; 
       }
       newNode->next = temp;    
       temp = newNode;    
    }
}


// Given a list, change it to be in sorted order (using SortedInsert()).
void InsertSort(catalog** headRef,char short_name[],char surname[],signed int amount,char description[])
{
 catalogPointer result = NULL;         // build the answer here
    catalogPointer current = *headRef;   // iterate over the original list
    catalogPointer next;     
    while (current!=NULL) 
 {
      next = current->next;    // tricky - note the next pointer before we change it
      SortedInsert(&result,current,short_name,surname,amount,description);
      current = next;
    } 
    *headRef = result;
}
```

Running the program I get these strange things (garbage?)...

> Choose your selection:
>
> > en james bond 007 gun
>
> Your command is: en james bond 007 gun
>
> temp is:james
>
> What you entered for saving: Short
>
> Name: james
>   SurName:
>   Amount: 0
>
> Description: 0T�Г
>
> Try to entry james  0 0T�Г in the
>   catalog list!
>
> **Entry done!**

Also I'm facing a problem on how to use the 'malloc' on this program.

Thanks in advance. . .

UPDATE:
I made an other function for entry. But somehow strange i get segmentation for strcpy!
That's it:

```
catalogPointer newEntry (char short_name[], char surname[], signed int amount, char description[])
{ 
 catalogPointer newNode,first,second,tmp;
 first=head;
 second=NULL;
 strcpy(newNode->short_name, short_name); //SEGMENTATION
    strcpy(newNode->surname, surname);
    newNode->amount=amount;
    strcpy(newNode->description, description);

 while (first!=NULL)      
 {     if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)>0)
   second=first;
  else if (strcmp(surname,first->surname)==0)
       {
      if (strcmp(short_name,first->short_name)>0)
   second=first;
  }
  first=first->next;
 }
 if (second==NULL)
 {     newNode->next=head;
  head=newNode;
 }
 else
 {      tmp=second->next;
           newNode->next=tmp;
           first->next=newNode;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

The direct reason of your problem is here:

```
while (command[j]!=' ' && command[j]!='\0') 
 { temp[k]=command[j];    
  j++;      
  k++;      
 }
```

What you are doing here is copying the contents of `command` into `temp` *until the first space character*. That is, you only copy `"james"`. Thus after the short name, there is nothing more for [`strtok`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to parse, so the other buffers don't get initialized properly and contain only garbage.

**Update:** To copy stuff *after the first space character*, use [`strchr`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) and [`strcpy`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) instead of that loop:

```
char* params = strchr(command, ' ') + 1;
strcpy(temp, params);
```

### Other observations

Apart from this, you give the size of the destination buffer incorrectly here:

```
strncpy(surname, curToken, sizeof (char *));
```

should be

```
strncpy(surname, curToken, 49);
```

Secondly: the loop expression in

```
for (n = 0; curToken !='\0'; ++n)
```

should be

```
for (n = 0; curToken; ++n)
```

otherwise the loop will not terminate correctly when all tokens have been parsed.

Comment: @Peter Torok: 
1st observation:
maybe that's right...but i just left it like that 'cause i wanna use after malloc...anyway that one didn't change anything on the running! :( –
2nd observation: i checked it, that also doesn't affect anything!

Comment: @Peter Torok: But how strcpy will 'cut' the elements on each whitespace?

Comment: @FILIaS, it is not supposed to cut anything, just copy the whole command into temp - `strtok` will cut the elements.

Comment: @Peter Torok:Yes but i used this while in order temp to dont contain 'en'  (enter) but only the rest of it  (eg command: en james bond 7 gun  temp:james bond 7 gun) temp is there in order to keep the command but without the first 2 letters (used to be on menu selection)

Comment: @Peter Torok: For update: Thank you! That's it! I always forget about strchr! Thaanxx

Comment: @FILIaS, actually an even simpler solution is to tokenize the command string as is and simply omit the first token...

Comment: @Peter Torok: Why is this '+1' there? for null?

Comment: @FILIaS, `strchr` returns a pointer to the first space within the command. You want a pointer to the char right _after_ that space.

Comment: @FILIaS, `strtok(temp," "); curToken = strtok(NULL," ");`

Comment: Thank you Peter Torok! Please as you 're still here,could you propose me a way to use malloc? I have given maximum number to strings...but i wanna save as much memory as each name of the user is.

Comment: @FILIaS, e.g. `char* short_name = malloc(strlen(curToken) + 1);`

Comment: @Peter Torok. when i get acceptable answers I click on the mark ;) Until now only on 2 questions i've get one!

Comment: @Peter Torok, except these do you maybe observe any other fault on the rest code? Because the datas arent written on the list :((

Comment: @FILIaS, apparently you start with an empty list (`head` is initialized to NULL) and `InsertSort` doesn't handle empty lists properly. Moreover, it seems to me that in a nonempty list, all elements will be overwritten with the new data. Moreover in `SortedInsert`, `(*headRef)->surname >= newNode->surname` will not compare two strings, but two pointers - use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: @FILIaS, `newNode` is not initialized. IMHO you should not edit and modify your original question endlessly - this is already a different problem from your original, so you should post a new question.

Comment: @Peter.My problem was the entry function.That's why i posted there another version of it.Anyway, should i put newNode to null? :///

Comment: @FILIaS, that's what I mean. And you should [`malloc`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) the new node since you want to store something in it. I'm gonna leave soon so I won't be checking SO much further. Post a new question if you still have problems.

Comment: @Peter Torok. it just needed malloc without initialization. thanx

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be filling `command` with anything, so you are tokenising whatever garbage was on the stack.

Comment: Yes that seems to be.But how then can I take the command? and each word between spaces?

Comment: well, where should the command come from? a disk file, a database, console input, gui? either read it in somewhere, and pass it as a parameter, or read it in in your function.

Comment: command comes from user,from console input. That's solved.Thanks to Peter Torok.